# Proving set function is measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. For each $E \in \Sigma$ we define $$\mu_0(E)=\sup\{\mu(F): F \in \Sigma, F \subset E, \mu(F)<\infty\}$$

I got stuck trying to show $\sigma$-additivity, take $(E_j)_{j \in \mathbb N}$ pairwise disjoint, if $E=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} E_j$, I want to prove $$\mu_0(E)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu_0(E_j)$$

I could show the inequality $$\mu_0(E)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu_0(E_j)$$It remains to show the other inequality:

For each $F_j \in E_j$ with $\mu(F_j)<\infty$, we have $\cup_{j=1}^N F_j \subset \cup_{j=1}^{\infty} F_j \subset E$, so $$\mu_0(E) \geq \mu(\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} F_j)$$$$ \geq  \mu(\cup_{j=1}^N F_j)$$$$=\sum_{j=1}^N \mu(F_j)$$

I got stuck here, I need to take supremum of each $\mu(F_j)$, but I don't know if the inequality keeps holding by taking supremum of each measure.

Comment: I think you first inequality $\mu _0 (E) \geq \mu (\bigcup _{j = 1} ^\infty F_j)$ may not hold in general as it is possible that $\mu (\bigcup _{j = 1} ^\infty F_j) = \infty$. Anyways if this is the case, you can generate a sequence $\{ \mu (\bigcup _{n = 1} ^j (F_n)) \}_{j = 1} ^\infty$ that approached $\infty$ to show that $\mu _0 (E) = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you take the supremum over all possible choices of $F_j$ on both sides, the inequality is still preserved, but the left side doesn't depend on the $F_j$, so the supremum doesn't change it. With $N$ still fixed, the supremum of the sum is the sum of the suprema, which is what you want. Now you send $N \to \infty$ to finish.